# Pre-requisites for studying differential geometry?

Tags: differential-geometry

I am an 3rd year undergrad interested in mathematics.i had read h.graham flengg (from geometry to topology).i found this field interesting i now want to read further,so i want to ask these questions

i) prerequisites to read differential geometry?

ii) research potential in this field ?

iii) time required to get feeling of this topic?

Comment: You might see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531932/research-in-differential-geometry?rq=1

Comment: To understand DG I would say a solid background in Calculus and linear algebra is helpful. Some basic understanding of topology is needed.