# What's it like researching Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry

I am an undergraduate and want to go into pure math research once I've finished my degree. I think Differential Geometry looks like a really interesting area and also enjoy the classes I have took in it so far.

I am wondering what it is like day to day as an academic studying this area, what current mainstream research in this area is about and what a typical day might be like.

Thanks.

Comment: Here a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531932/research-in-differential-geometry?rq=1

Comment: It differs from time to time ;P